# Clicking on button within dropdown menu

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium to automate translation of some text from english to Japanese .link is present here [translate at deepl.com](https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/de/In%20the%20Name%20of%20Allah%2C%20Most%20Gracious%2C%20Most%20Merciful%20%20Indo-Pakistani%20wars%20and%20conflicts%3A%20Since%20the%20partition%20of%20India%2C%20there%20have%20been%20numerous%20armed%20conflicts%20between%20India%20and%20Pakistan.%20Since%201947%2C%20the%20two%20South%20Asian%20countries%20have%20been%20involved%20in%20four%20wars%2C%20including%20one%20undeclared%20war%2C%20as%20well%20as%20many%20border%20skirmishes%20and%20military%20stand-offs.%20Additionally%2C%20India%20has%20accused%20Pakistan%20of%20engaging%20in%20proxy%20wars%20by%20providing%20military%20and%20financial%20assistance%20to%20violent%20non-state%20actors.%20The%20dispute%20for%20Kashmir%20has%20been%20the%20cause%2C%20whether%20direct%20or%20indirect%20of%20all%20major%20conflicts%20between%20the%20two%20countries%20with%20the%20exception%20of%20the%20Indo-Pakistani%20War%20of%201971%2C%20where%20the%20dispute%20concerned%20the%20East%20Pakistan.%20%20%20%201) I am having trouble in clicking on 'Translate Into japanese' button in drop down of Translate into. I am attaching photo for more clarity here [click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I8ob.jpg). I used xpaths but sometimes they work and sometimes they just translate to russian instead of japanese. How should this button be located. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a drop-down menu value with Selenium using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python)

Comment: @eNc No, I checked , it doesnot help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And pass some expected conditions before clicking the buttons :

```
driver.get('https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/de/...')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//button[@class='lmt__language_select__active'])[2]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//button[@dl-lang='JA'])[2]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//textarea)[2]"))).click()
trad = [el.text for el in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='lmt__textarea_base_style']/span[text()]")))]
print("".join(trad))
```

Alternatives : use the API ([see @Bertrand Martel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62219517/9978746)), or replace directly "de" with "ja" in your request url.

https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/de... to https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/ja...

EDIT : If the second click fail you can use `ActionChains` :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//button[@dl-lang='JA'])[2]")))).click().perform()
```

Comment: Inserted your snippet and it raises same exception as before : raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button tabindex="100" dl-lang="JA" dl-test="translator-lang-option-ja-JA" dl-short-lang="...">Japanese</button> is not clickable at point (700, 497). Other element would receive the click: <div>...</div>

Comment: Using https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/ja/ works when used manually but strangely with automated browser, language changes to german instead of japanese.

Comment: Above code worked with using firefox browser instead of chrome browser.

Comment: Great. I've added an alternative with "ActionChains" for the second click.